# WSO2: API Manager; calling publish api from webservice

Tags: wso2

Is it possible to call the WSO2 API Manager:: publisher api, as described in:

http://docs.wso2.org/display/AM150/Publisher+APIs

From a webservice, instead fronm JSON

Greetz,

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call those jaggery endpoints from webservices.
Do a simple HTTP Post to those endpoints;

Eg:

```
// create a post request to addAPI.
String addAPIendpoint = "http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(addAPIendpoint);

// Request parameters and other properties.
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(12);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(API_ACTION, API_ADD_ACTION));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(API_NAME, serviceName));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(API_CONTEXT, serviceName));
.....

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, httpContext);
```